# Как правильно произносится слово "Псалтирь"

Tags: орфоэпия

"Т" здесь произносится как [т] или [т']?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Изначально Псалтирь(ж.р.)Псалтирь (от греч. псалтирион, ψαλτήριον – название струнного музыкального инструмента) – книга, входящая в состав Библии, которая состоит из 150 песней или псалмов .
Наименование Псалтири взято от музыкального струнного инструмента, с игрою на котором соединялось пение псалмов при ветхозаветном богослужении.

Современное светское название Псалтырь(муж.р. и жен.р.). Так что если хочется говорить по-библейски, то мягко,если по-светски - твёрдо (это разговорный вариант, допускающий вольности современного произношения)

Comment: >Современное светское название Псалтырь(муж.р. и жен.р.).

А родительный падеж можно узнать как будет выглядеть? В муж. и жен. р. Если можно, то с ударением, пожалуйста.

А в имен. падеже ударение на последний слог?

**Марк Из**, хороший вопрос. +1.

Comment: Кстати, насколько я знаю, изначально псалтирь - это музыкальный инструмент. Так вот он какого рода: мужского или женского?

Comment: 1.Муз. инструмент-жен. рода:Десятиструнная псалтЫрь. Играть на псалтЫри.
 2.Nikolja, склонение:ж.р.-а)Р.Д.П.псалтЫри Т.псалтЫрью
б)муж.р.-Р.псалтырЯ,Д.псалтырЮ,Т.псалтырЁм,П.о псалтырЕ 
http://ru.oldict.com/%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8C/
http://www.bravica.ws/ru/accents/word_34547.htm
http://www.reright.ru/analysis/?word=1506814

Comment: Муж.род-разговорное